# Azure Function on consumption plan cold start can be up to 30 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function v3, written in C#, using the class library approach.

- The function is triggered by blob storage.
- The function is using a Consumption plan.

The problem is that **cold starts can be as long as 30 minutes**! I have consulted the documentation from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#cold-start-behavior)

But there is no specific figures with regards to expected cold start timings.

An interesting observation is that if I navigate to the portal, and hit Refresh button:

[image]

Then the function gets immediately triggered.

1. Is this normal, expected behavior?
2. Could you please point me to any docs explicitly stating that ~0-30-50mins is OK for cold starts on Consumption Plan?

Comment: I've never seen any 30min cold start for an azure function running on a consumption plan. It typically few seconds. The documentation you're pointintg at doesn't say at all that cold start is up to 30min ?

Comment: I guess this question has been posted by a competitor to defame the reputation of the cloud provider. Azure Functions app start on our production app in avg. between 1-2s (JavaScript)

Comment: Check the link to the docs you added: You are confusing cold start times with default timeout durations (30min). The timeout duration defines how long your function can execute one request. Even that can be configured if you have special requirements.

Comment: I doubt either cold start or timeout fits into a delay of "forever", until you go to the azure  portal and hit refresh on the AzFn's overview page, so that the function gets kicked in the but to trigger. We had to upgrade to latest version (at the time) in order to fix this.

Comment: I have an Azure Function Triggered by Cold Blob Storage and it takes 7-10 minutes, each time a file arrives to trigger. The Azure function is Premium and always awake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumption plan is what azure calls "serverless" model; what it means -

> your code reacts to events, effectively scales out to meet whatever load you’re seeing, scales down when code isn’t running, and you’re billed only for what you use.

Cold start is nothing but the

> phenomenon that applications which haven’t been used take longer to start up.

When you're using the Consumption plan, instances of the Azure Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events.

If you've a "heavy-weight" code written and deployed on consumption plan which takes lot of memory and resources to get loaded to execute it may take more time such as your case.
When you hit the refresh button from portal - The Functions runtime resets, and any required extensions are loaded onto the worker and gets loaded into the memory. That's why it reduces most of the latency.

To understand more about the cold-start in azure serverless model & how you can minimize that please refer here - [Understanding serverless cold start](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/)

To reduce it more; you can have a warmup request which will hit based on time interval and you'll have your function always loaded in memory.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm afraid I need exact figures with SLA's on Consumption Plan, before trying to apply a solution. Diving into the details of the underlying implementation  for of how azure provisions its hardware, is definitely an interesting topic, but a bit out of context. Thanks!

Comment: Here you can get the required details about the SLA for consumption plan. [SLA for Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/functions/v1_1/#:~:text=For%20Function%20Apps%20running%20on,after%20trigger%20is%20successfully%20fired.&text=We%20will%20provide%20at%20least,material%20changes%20to%20this%20SLA.)

Comment: Hmm had a look, 99.95% uptime AFTER being triggered. But nothing with regards to actual trigger delay due to cold starts.

Comment: Yup that why I mentioned all the scenarios; because the delay on cold start can be dependent on code, resources, function host. Those factors will be different for each customer; if you think from Microsoft Azure point of view.

Comment: We know if the app is idle for more than 20 minutes it will go into cold state; however when we trigger it there are many factors comes into picture for the start time to get it back in loaded state

Comment: If you follow this thread; you'll get more info on the open issues related to same. However its not the same but will help you to understand it in better way - [Cold Start Open Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3965)

Comment: I do understand the circumstances, however without an explicit statement like: "It could take from 20sec - 24hr / infinity" Its hard to make a decision in its favor isn't it? I'm surprised they do not provide exact figures, even if its in form of a range, with a SLA of 9XXX% that the range will be met. Surely its not a non-deterministic problem? There must be a hard stop

Comment: I agree with your statement; however in your case it's quite strange that it's taking too much time frankly speaking. I never ran into such case even when I have multiple apps running with large code on it. For that kind of range I never found an official statement/doc from azure.

Answer (score 4):

That is not correct, you're referring to a timeout duration - which is not equivalent to a cold start. If your function takes that long, its cause there was an exception/error (I don't mean an exception in code). No where in any documentation (even by microsoft) does it say that cold starts takes 30 mins.

If cold starts are taking too long (>~1 min) and you're sure there arent any startup errors - break your functions down and trigger those functions parallelly (where possible). Application Insights is your friend here.

Lastly, there are no exact figures - its such a per use basis. There are many things that effects execution time - which might lead one to blame cold starts, rather than the responsibilities & dependencies of a function. With Functions/Lambda, its not just "code like any other API", there is also some architectural changes.

What I would definitely like to know is the performance difference (esp cold start) if the code is published to Azure Function as a code vs in a docker (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/function-app-container?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). I'll try to find some time to perform a good experiment on this and report back (no promises).

Further Readings -

1. Crude Cold Start Timing Study: https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/azure/ (he has performed the same experiment with AWS Lambda)
2. Another good comparative study of Lambda & Functions: https://azurefromthetrenches.com/comparative-performance-of-azure-functions-and-aws-lambda/
3. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/

EDIT:
Though this is slightly old Github Issue Thread, the maximum reported cold start time on this thread is about 2 mins; seems the average is somewhere around 20s. Note the Engineering Manager in Microsoft Azure (David Ebbo) at the time mentions that it shouldn't take longer than 10s for trivial functions.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/838

**EDIT 2: The 30 mins timeout duration is for non-consumption plans (5mins for consumption plan), so I assume you're planning to use non-consumption plans, in which case you're not going to have cold start issues. The other plans keep the functions warm.**
Please go through "Overview Of Plans" in the document you linked - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#overview-of-plans

Answer (score 1):

In general cold starts occur when your function hasn’t run in ~20 minutes

To avoid it, if you run your code frequently enough that it stays warm cold starts won’t occur (unless if you scale out)

A common way for doing this is making a simple “invoker” helper function which calls your function every `5/10 minutes`

if that doesn’t fit for your solution and if you’re ok to pay slightly more, you can run your Function in the Dedicated plan.

Regarding [SLA on Consumption Plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/functions/v1_1/):

> “Unavailable Executions” is the total number of executions within
> Total Triggered Executions which failed to run. An execution failed to
> run when the given Function App history log did not capture any output
> five (5) minutes after the trigger is successfully fired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Invoker solution defeats the idea behind a Consumption Plan, as it will drive the price up effectively becoming a standard plan. Before trying to create ping/warmup cycles I'd want to understand exact figures of expected cold start for a Consumption Plan. Thanks!

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/functions/v1_1/ check here

Comment: @CristianE. on consumption plan you pay per execution and per execution time. I have some functions with health check behind a load balancer and it s just costing me few $ per month tho.

Answer (score -3):

No this is not normal. A cold start shouldn't take too long. [Here](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/azure/)  is a recent performance test that should give you your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The provided resource is a blog post made by one of the customers. I was hoping to get exact SLA's for the Consumption Plan in order to understand if its acceptable to wait X minutes before a start happens.