# Optimize Durable functions C#

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-durable-functions

I am running with a performance issue with the service bus queue-based durable function.

Here is the scenario,

```
    public async Task KickOff(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(Constants.QueueName, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
        ProcessExecution objectFromQueue,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        //Call Orchestration
        await client.StartNewAsync(nameof(SubOrchestration), "My Instance", objectFromQueue);
    }


    [FunctionName(nameof(SubOrchestration))]
    public async Task<Result> SubOrchestration(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        // Call Sub Orchestration
        var result = await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<Result<MyObjectResult>>(nameof(TaskSubOrchestration), context);
    }

   [FunctionName(nameof(TaskSubOrchestration))]
   public async Task<Result<MyObjectResult>> TaskSubOrchestration(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
    ILogger logger)
   {
      //Call context.CallActivityAsync1

      //Call context.CallActivityAsync2

      //Call context.CallActivityAsync3
   }
```

It shows inconsistent behaviour for all the above Orchestration executions. Sometimes, it takes 15-20 or 50 seconds to complete the entire operation.

I have verified the logs in the Azure App Insights, and I am confused with this behaviour. I see there is no time in the execution of each Activity/SubOrchestration, but it takes time to invoke the SubOrchestration.

In most cases, it takes 15-20 seconds to invoke

> SubOrchestration

> TaskSubOrchestration

The Orchestration execution time is less, but most of the time is taken to invoke this 2 Orchestration.

Can you please help me if there is any way to optimize the functions in azure or if I am missing anything in the implementation?

Comment: You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505063/68972) or [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3965) in case it's related with cold start and your actual plan

Comment: Thank you, Jcl; as I mentioned in my question, I observed that it is not a severe code issue, and it doesn't take time to execute sub Orc after triggered. The main problem is with the time it takes to start the SubOrchestration.