# How to bind CosmosDB and Event Grid to Azure Durable Functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-durable-functions, azure-eventgrid

I would like to use Durable functions to connect to services such as CosmosDB and Event Grid.

I created the code to connect to CosmosDB and Event Grid by referring to the official MS documentation. The following is the code.

However, it does not work because I get an error like the one shown in the picture.
Please let me know the cause and solution.

I am using Python programming model v2.

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None)
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)
    return f"runtime: {status.runtime_status}\n\noutput:\n {status.output}" 

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> dict:
    test = yield context.call_activity('main', '')
    return {"result", connected}


@app.cosmos_db_output(arg_name="outputDocument", 
                      database_name="MyDatabase",
                      collection_name="MyCollection",
                      connection_string_setting="MyAccount_COSMOSDB")
@app.event_grid_output(arg_name="outputEvent",
                       topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting",
                       topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def main(blank: str, 
         outputblob: func.Out[str], 
         outputDocument: func.Out[func.Document]):

    return "ok"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qk1e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `container_name` instead of `collection_name`  and for connection, use `connection` instead of `connection_string_setting` for extension version 4.x. You can refer to this [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=python-v2,isolated-process,nodejs-v4,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#example).

I have used the below code and getting expected result.

```py
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
import  logging


app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)  

### client function ###

@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
status  =  await  client.get_status(instance_id)
return  f"runtime: {status.runtime_status}\n\noutput: {status.output}"

### orchestrator function ###

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def  orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> dict:
test  =  yield  context.call_activity("main", "")
return {"Connected": test}  

### activity function ###
# I want to calculate the value and output it to the bound service.

@app.cosmos_db_output(arg_name="outputDocument",
database_name="MyDatabase",
container_name="MyCollection",
connection="MyAccount_COSMOSDB")

@app.event_grid_output(arg_name="outputEvent",
topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting",
topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def  main(blank: str,
outputEvent: func.Out[str],
outputDocument: func.Out[func.Document]):
return  "OK"
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to run it successfully.
Do you think the cold start time will be longer just by connecting without writing data like this?
Or do you think writing the code to write the data will further increase the cold start time?

Comment: I believe cold start is something to do with function app start time if it's not running. Please refer the accepted answer of this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504904/azure-function-on-consumption-plan-cold-start-can-be-up-to-30-minutes

Comment: I believe, it will be more if we are write the data

Comment: If the application is in a warm state, does the response time change much whether there are many or few connections to external services?

Comment: AFAIK, response time will differ based on the operations you are performing. For external connections, it might but not much