Azure HTTP function timeouts & terminations despite trivial CosmosDB query
Our HTTP Trigger Azure functions are experiencing intermittent but persistent timeouts,
despite their very simple content of querying a small volume of CosmosDB records.
Even our 'ping' HTTP function that is called by monitoring (Pingdom) exhibits this behaviour. It executes a SELECT 1 type statement on CosmosDB which completes in milliseconds then returns. No capacity/RU issue on the Cosmos side.
Using consumption plan, functions v4, .NET 8 isolated. No auth or tricky code - just simple CRUD functions. Very low traffic volumes (<1000 calls/day over all functions).
The Functions 'Failures' blade demonstrates the problem:

All functions, including ping above, receive the cosmos DB connection via constructor IoC:
Program.cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
        services.AddSingleton(s => ... return new CosmosClientBuilder(connectionString).Build())
        services.AddTransient(s => return client.GetDatabase(dbName).GetContainer(containerName));
    )

PingFunction.cs
...
public class HealthApi(ILogger<HealthApi> logger, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container){
    [Function($"{nameof(HealthApi)}_{nameof(Ping)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Ping(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "head", Route = "adm/health/ping")]
        HttpRequest req)

    var qry = client.Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<DbCategory>()
        .Where(c => c.id == "1");

    var feed = qry.ToFeedIterator();
    while (feed.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var ignored = await feed.ReadNextAsync();
    }

    return new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        status = "ok",
    }));
}

What could cause this behaviour? We are fairly confident it is not related to the CosmosDB connection.
Update 1 - screenshot of executions taking more than 5 minutes for the ping function/basic cosmos query. Confused how it could possibly take this long?


How often is your ping ?

Ping call is every 5 minutes

in consumption plan, there is an issue called 'cold start', if there are no calls, then Azure will shutdown the instances, and when a new http call arrives to your function app, it will restart a new instance and load your function app binaries. There are some ways to overcome this, like "run from package" setting set to 1, for production env, you could go with premium with "pre warmed" instances.

Definitely sounds like cold start.

Thanks @AnandSowmithiran and ArchitectJamie - you could be right. I would have though ping every 5m would keep at least 1 instance alive?  Could it also somehow explain the verrrry long execution time of some of the functions, eg ping (added Update 1 to my post with screenshot)

Cold start on Consumption Plan is in the order of a few seconds; not 5 minutes. I think it's something else. Here's an answer with some good sources quoted on cold start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70269935/2325216
